# Do power series converge uniformly and absolutely on radius of convergence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-explanation, power-series, uniform-convergence, absolute-convergence

I was reading [this](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/%7Ehunter/intro_analysis_pdf/ch10.pdf) text on power series. On pages $182-183$, the author gives a proof of the following statement:

> Let
> $$
> \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n (x-c)^n
> $$
> be a power series. There is a non-negative, extended real number $0 \le R \le \infty$ such that the series converges absolutely for  for $0 ≤ |x − c| < R$ and diverges for
> $|x − c| > R$. Furthermore, if $0 ≤ \rho < R$, then the power series converges uniformly
> on the interval $|x − c| ≤ \rho$.

During the proof, the author first proves that the series converges absolutely by bounding $|a_nx^n|$ using inequalities leading to a geometric series, and then using that the common ratio is $<1$ to conclude the series is $< \infty$. After this, the author then proves that the series converges uniformly on $|x − c| \le \rho$ by again using inequalities that lead to a geometric series, but this time he uses the  Weierstrass M-test to conclude that the series converges uniformly.

This left me a bit confused because it is my understanding that from the M-test you can conclude that the series is *both* uniformly and absolutely convergent. And since the statement of the theorem allows for $|x − c| = \rho$, I don't understand why the author separates the statement (and the proof) into two parts when I believe you could simplify it to

> Let
> $$
> \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n (x-c)^n
> $$
> be a power series. There is a non-negative, extended real number $0 \le R \le \infty$ such that the series converges uniformly and absolutely for $0 ≤ |x − c| < R$ and diverges for
> $|x − c| > R$.

Is there a reason to introduce the number $\rho$ which I'm missing? Or can the text actually be simplified like this? Thank you!

Comment: Because it is false that it converges uniformly for $|x-c|<R$

Comment: The M's in the M test get bigger as you get closer to the boundary, so it won't work for the entire interval.

Comment: A rule of thumb : "everything can happen on the circle of convergence". There are some deep theorems with particular conditions for having such and such type of convergence in a given point of the circle of convergence. See for example [here](https://andrescaicedo.files.wordpress.com/2014/11/korner-behaviourofpowerseries.pdf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This final statement of yours is false. Take, for instance, the geometric series$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n.\tag1$$The only $R$ for which it is both true that the series $(1)$ converges absolutely when $|x|<R$ and that it diverges when $|x|>R$ is $R=1$. However, the series $(1)$ does *not* converge uniformly when $|x|<1$. On the other hand, for each $\rho\in(0,1)$ the series $(1)$ does converge uniformly when $|x|\leqslant\rho$.

However, it is true that if you prove that a power series$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(x-c)^n\tag2$$converges uniformly when $|x-c|\leqslant\rho$, for each $\rho<R$ and if that proof uses the Weierstrass $M$-test, then you can deduce from that proof that the series $(2)$ converges absolutely when $|x-c|<R$.

Comment: Thank you for the counterexample! I still don't understand why my reasoning that $|x − c| \le \rho$ and $ 0 ≤ |x − c| \le \rho < R$ implies $ 0 ≤ |x − c|  < R$ is wrong. Can you tell me where my mistake is?

Comment: Please read my new paragraph.

Comment: So is the statement assuming less general hypothesis by letting $|x − c| \le \rho$ instead of $|x − c| < \rho$, or did I misunderstand your answer?

Comment: I think that you are misunderstanding it, yes. The statement that you quoted from the textbook is correct. My second paragraph only explained how using the Weierstrass $M$-test allows us to prove the uniform convergence on $\{x\in\Bbb R\mid|x-c|\leqslant\rho\}$ for each $\rho<R$ **and** also to prove absolute convergence on $\{x\in\Bbb R\mid|x-c|<R\}$.

Comment: I think I understand now. So the statement is correct, and it is also correct that the proof of uniform convergence using the M-test proves the absolute convergence part, but my statement where I attempted to simplify is false, right?

Comment: That is correct, yes.

Answer (score 0):

In the first blockqoute $\rho < R$ is need in case the series does not converge at $x = c \pm R$. That is
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n (\pm R)^n = \pm \infty
$$
then the convergence on $|x-c|<R$ is not uniform.

*Added*: if the series converges on $(c-R,c+R)$ but *not* at $x = c \pm R$, then there is (actually for all) $\varepsilon >0$ such  that the partial sums differ from the limit function on $(c-R,c+R)$ by more than that $\varepsilon$, since the limit function is unbounded near $x = c \pm R$, in contrast to any partial sum.

Comment: I don't understand what your answer brings... Besides what is a "blockqoute" ?

Comment: sorry for the late reply, blockquote is the box in which you stated the theorems

Comment: I added sth to the answer

Comment: Thanks for the answer and sorry for the stupid question. I imagined that it was an unknown word for a kind of mathematical object or whatever... :)

Answer (score -1):

Fixing $\rho < R$ allows you to use
$(\rho/R)^n \to 0$.